# How to use index.js instead of (index.ios.js, index.android.js) in React Native for cross-platform app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, cross-platform

Thanks for the answers from now,

I am a newbie in **React Native**, I want to make a cross-platform app so I created index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Component,
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

class ReactApp extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View><Text>Hello world</Text></View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = ReactApp;
```

Then I imported index.js from both index.ios.js and index.android.js like this:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import ReactApp from './index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactApp', () => ReactApp);
```

I think after this it should work but I get this 
error:

[image]

Comment: please rename index file and try again

Comment: Your image is not working. Also, you didn't state what you were trying to accomplish by doing this.

Comment: @MichaelCheng image is working I think cause I tried on my phone also, I want to make a cross-platform app

Comment: @ravi.p like how? and why?

Comment: @davutdev It's working now. Umm... "I want to make a cross-platform app". Ok, let me rephrase. What is the intended behavior you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to use a single entry point file, `index.js`, instead of two separate ones for iOS and Android? Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: @MichaelCheng Yes, I just want to code in index.js and run it on both ios and android, you are right that's what I want to do

Comment: @davutdev have u tried ? cause may be it is conflict with name "index.js" so just try

Comment: @ravi.p Nope unfortunately, same issue :/

Comment: replace first line in index.js with this and try                                           
import React, {Component} from 'react';

Comment: @RaviPanchal is right - you can't use `Component` without importing it directly from react.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

After React v0.49, you don't need `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js`. You only need the `index.js`:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './app/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('appMobile', () => App);
```

(replace `appMobile` with the name of your app)

Source: (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0)

> New projects have a single entry-point (index.js) from now on

Comment: That was about I was looking for, because I've worked with other version (older) and I saw the 2 different files, but from 0.49 you will get one file after create the app.

Comment: If you want to upgrade your RN version check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html (`react-native-git-upgrade` should work like a charme)

Comment: is it possible to still use 2 files with new react-native?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: The issue explaining something: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246#issuecomment-336943492

Comment: After trying to find a solution for a few hours, this was the only one that worked.

Answer (score 7):

You're going about this backwards. `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` will always be separate entry points in a default `react-native init` project. If you want to have them run the same codebase via `index.js`, you should set it up so `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` import `index.js` and registers the same base component as defined in `index.js`.

For example, you can look at how it's done in this [example ToDo app](http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/todo_list) ([Github repo here](https://github.com/gabergg/ReactNativeTodoList)).

If you place `index.js` in your root folder, it will conflict with `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` when you don't reference it directly. So you will need to point to the exact path in your import. See the code below.

**index.ios.js** and **index.android.js** (same contents)

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import ReactApp from './index.js'
// Had you placed index.js in another folder like `./app`, you could instead do your import with this shorthand:
// import ReactApp from './app'

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactApp', () => ReactApp)
```

**index.js**

```
// Note: I noticed that you imported Component from the wrong place. That might also be contributing to your issue so I fixed it here.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

// Unless you are exporting multiple things from a single file, you should just use this.
// It's more idiomatic than using module.exports = ReactApp;
export default class ReactApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View><Text>Hello world</Text></View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code but I am getting the same error :-/ ,

Comment: @davutdev Try it now with the edits. I missed the React import since I put the answer together really quickly. You still need that in all three files. Also, realized that the shorthand `./index` import will have a naming conflict if you place `index.js` in the same directory as other files starting with `index.something`. Had you used another filename or placed it elsewhere, that wouldn't have been an issue. I added comments to explain it in the answer. I also tested this in a brand new project just now so if there are any errors still, it must be from something else.

Answer (score 6):

In iOS AppDelegate.m change this

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

to

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```