# React Native - file structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am very new to React native and following a series of tutorials from Udemy and the thing is suddenly in a tutorial his file structure changed from **index.js** to **index.ios.js** and **index.android.js**

what is the difference between index.js and (**index.ios.js **index.android.js**).

My code is:

```
// library
import React from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistery } from 'react-native'; 

//component 
const App = () => (
  <Text>Some text</Text>
);

AppRegistery.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

Error Message:

[image]

Comment: typo - `AppRegistry`

Comment: React Native files with an `.ios` suffix will only be loaded on iOS and you guessed it, the `.android` suffix will only be loaded on Android. If both files are identical, you can delete both and create a `index.js` file.

Comment: Just the difference between application portal according different platform,`index.js` usually contains identical contents.Please check this,[How to use index.js instead of (index.ios.js, index.android.js) in React Native for cross-platform app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803681/how-to-use-index-js-instead-of-index-ios-js-index-android-js-in-react-native?rq=1)